# Updating a zero-length string in Oracle

Tags: oracle

In our current database (migrated from a sql database) we have a table x with a column y(varchar2 (4000)) that is not nullable. The table and column are filled with data and I should update the data in column y to a 'zero-length string'. I'm not able to, altough the internet tells me I should by using this value '\u00A0'. It doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

ps: I can't change the column to nullable... So that's not an option

Comment: The requirement does not seem to make sense. There is no such thing as a zero-length, non-NULL `varchar2` value.  The value `\u00A0` is not a zero-length string, it is a Unicode non-breaking space so it would result in a string of at least 1 byte, probably more, depending on your database character set. I'm hard-pressed to understand why you would want to use a Unicode non-breaking space rather than a space. It is not clear what "not able to" means-- what is the query you are running, what is the error you are receiving?

Comment: SQL Server and Oracle treat empty strings differently.  Oracle considers an empty string to be NULL; SQL Server does not.  So, it's not possible to insert an empty string into a not-nullable column in Oracle.

Comment: There is no "zero-length" string in Oracle. Oracle treats that as `NULL`

Comment: @JustinCave: The requirement makes a little sense. Our current application is running in different companies (up to this point all with sql server). A few months ago we got a contract with another big company, but they use a oracle database. We rebuild our own framework so our application is the same code-wise, only the DB is different. So that's why we are looking for a 'zero-lenght' string that oracle does not consider null (we want our DB from oracle and sql to be the same...). At this moment it is filled with a regular space, but our application crashes... Stupid Oracle!

Comment: Or stupid sales people for not checking the implications of the change with the technical team -- although the technical team does not appear to have done its research on "Differences between SQL Server and Oracle" in this case. Your application code will need to be changed.

Comment: @DavidAldridge: yes, but I'm not allowed to say that. It seems like it will be the application code - more time, so more expensive...

Comment: The truth should never be unspoken. Your company got into this mess by agreeing to change the database technology in order to get a large sale without fully assessing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Justin, this requirement doesn't make sense. But there is a trick that can do this, although it's usually a bad idea. **I have to emphasize however that I would (almost) NEVER EVER do this in a real system.**

```
ALTER TABLE x MODIFY y NULL;

UPDATE x SET y = '' WHERE ...;

ALTER TABLE x MODIFY y NOT NULL NOVALIDATE;
```

This temporarily drops the constraint, updates the row(s) which need to be set NULL, then re-applies the constraint but with the NOVALIDATE option.

I repeat, however, this is **not a good idea** because this may have a detrimental effect on queries - the optimiser will no longer be able to assume that the values in this column are not null, so if (e.g.) you have an index on the column, some queries will no longer use the index.

Also, you can't allow other transactions to run while you're doing this, because the constraint won't be checked.

Comment: Cunning, but it still will not get the application working of course - doubtless it is querying "where column_name = '' " or similar.

Comment: Yes, I was answering the Q at literal face value "how to update a not-null column to null" :)